# gcc-10-ar thinks the invalid "." option is being passed to it

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, archive, source-engine

I'm compiling a game using the [Source Engine](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013). When I run make, after a while the archiver tool complains about an invalid option ".":

```
/usr/bin/ar: invalid option -- '.'
```

this happens with every archiver I have installed: `gcc-10-ar`, `llvm-10-ar`, and `busybox ar`.

The command the makefile is trying to run is:

```
gcc-ar-10 ../lib/public/linux32/raytrace.a ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/raytrace.o ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/trace2.o ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/trace3.o
```

I don't use the archiver tool often, but this looks like a valid command to me.
Normally the issue with those is that a dash is being prepended which makes the archiver tool think whatever is following it are the "mini options" like `-lm`

In my case there aren't any dashes at all. I think the `.` is from the path but that should be interpreted as a file path and not a command-line argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `ar` is supposed to be one or more characters indicating the operation to perform (optionally prefixed with `-`) and modifiers to this operation.

If you want to create a new archive from the object files, you probably want `rcs`, which asks `ar` to insert the listed files into the archive with replacement (`r`), create the archive if necessary (`c`) and to create an index for the archive (`s`).

So for example:

```
gcc-ar-10 rcs ../lib/public/linux32/raytrace.a ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/raytrace.o ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/trace2.o ./obj_raytrace_linux32/release/trace3.o
```

I assume that `ar` is giving you the error since it tries to interpret the first `.` of the first argument as one of these operation instructions.

See also `man ar`.

---

As for the linked repository (although I have no experience with it and this is just an observation based on looking at one file in it): It seems that the Makefile expects `AR`, if it is specified in the environment, to include not only the path to the executable, but also the above-mentioned options (see [this line](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/sp/src/devtools/makefile_base_posix.mak#L115) setting a default value).

This is not what is usually expected from the `AR` environment variable, so this is unconventional. A workaround is to add the `rcs` argument directly to the environment variable, e.g. if `AR` is already set in the environment as usual:

```
AR="$AR rcs" make
```

instead of

```
make
```

Don't set `AR` globally with these options, since other typical Makefiles will be confused by it.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this isn't there by default in the makefile though...

Comment: @TheAwesome98 I don't know where in the repository the relevant part of the Makefile is defined, so I can't tell you that.

Comment: I believe it's in devtools/makefile_base_posix.mak.

Comment: @TheAwesome98 There are two lines setting `AR` in there. One for linux, which correctly provides the options (https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/sp/src/devtools/makefile_base_posix.mak#L115) and one for Darwin (https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/sp/src/devtools/makefile_base_posix.mak#L220) which I don't know about.

Comment: @TheAwesome98 However, both are ignored if you set `AR` e.g. in your shell environment. The problem then is that `AR` typically is just `ar` or an equivalent path to the executable without options, while the Makefile expects the options as part of the variable. I feel that this is a wrong assumptions made by the Makefile, but a workaround is easy: Don't specify `AR` in the environment or specify it with the options. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I do specify AR in env, I'll try just restarting my terminal and running build without the env vars EDIT: just remembered why I specified them in the firt place: it defaults to a non existant path. How do I specify in the options? -DAR=(whatever)?

Comment: Actually I think I've fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, doing that is what fixed my problem, but I'm having a different problem now. I'll see if I can fix it and if not I will open another question.